# SQLite - Are there alternatives to rtree for indexing lines on an axis?

Tags: sql, sqlite, genetics

I'm trying to make a database of positions with a start and stop: basically lines on a 1D axis. I want to efficiently query all positions that overlap a given interval. In a traditional table, the query would require two inequalities, so it cannot be indexed. You can also use an R-Tree index, but they seem designed for multidimensional range queries. Is there a more efficient way to store lines on an axis?

If anybody curious, the database is to store genome intervals. Here's an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE lines (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, start INTEGER, stop INTEGER);
```

The basic way to do this is:

```
SELECT * FROM lines WHERE start <= <end of interval> AND stop >= <start of interval>;
```

Again, that's really slow and can't be indexed. The R-Tree would work like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE lines_index USING RTREE (id, start, stop);
SELECT * from lines_index WHERE start <= <end of interval> AND stop >= <start of interval>;
```

R-Trees aren't ideal for our implementation, so I'm wondering if there are any alternatives...

Comment: Why do you say that R-Trees aren't optimal for your implementation?  While they can handle multi-dimensional data, you can use them for 1-dimensional data as well.

Comment: Sorry, should have expanded there. I wrote some tests of rtree v. traditional indices, and rtree performed poorly. Our use case is very unique for a few reasons: 1) Most (~90%) of the variants are single points - start and stop are the same. 2) Tables are really big - tens of millions of rows. 3) Positions are integers, not floats. 4) variants are actually stored by chromosome AND position, so we do lots of post-query processing.

So, I was looking to see if there are any other options, like an interval tree.

Comment: I realize this is more than 2 years old, but I was wondering if you've tried the rtree_i32 R*Tree variant in sqlite that stores values as ints instead of floats.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, allthough you can't fully index it you could index by just the start interval. If 90% of the intervals have start=stop, that should make a big improvement. The only slowdown would be with very long intervals.

Comment: Problem is, what if you have an interval with start=100 and stop=200, and you want to query intervals that overlap 150-160. That'd require two inequalities, which is very very slow